# How to leverage CCSpriteBatchNode when frames are distributed into multiple textures

Tags: ios, cocos2d-iphone, ccsprite

In my game, there're plenty of enemies(subclass of `CCNode`) which animation frames are distributed into multiple texture files(enemy01.png, enemy02.png...) and enemies from different textures may be generated in the same scene.

I'd like to have a unified way to dynamically add a randomly generated enemy to the correct `CCSpriteBatchNode`, but a lookup table seems not so elegant. Is there any better way to handle it?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Since each enemy uses its own texture, you can use one sprite batch node per enemy. So when you create enemy "X" it shouldn't be hard to get the corresponding sprite batch node from wherever you store it (perhaps an NSDictionary).

Keep in mind that one sprite batch node per enemy kind of defies the purpose, especially if the texture atlas for each enemy is rather small and not even close to the maximum allowed size (1024x1024 for old devices, 2048x2048 or more for iPhone 3GS and newer). If possible, cram as many images into one texture atlas and use one sprite batch node for it.

Comment: I don't think one sprite batch node per enemy is reasonable in my case since each frame is far from being close to the max allowed size. I've already been placing as many images into one atlas as possible, but just want to find out a way to dynamically get which atlas the enemy's frames belonging to. NSDictionary lookup is a candidate which I used to think of but any other suggestion?